# moving svg box with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

This is a svg box which can move using arrow keys.

I want this box to stop when the arrows are realeased, and to continue moving accordingly to the key presed.

This app uses svg, js, and jquery.

I **have** looked and have found no answer. Please help the cause.

```js
$(function() {
 var y = 4;
  var x = 4;
 var n;
 var move;

 $(document).keydown(function(e) {
     switch(e.which) {
         case 37: // left
      move = setInterval(move_left, .1);
          break;
         case 38: // up
      move = setInterval(move_up, .1);
          break;
         case 39: // right
      move = setInterval(move_right, .1);
          break;
         case 40: // down
      move = setInterval(move_down, .1);
          break;
         default:
      return;
     }
     e.preventDefault();
 });

 function move_left() {
    $("#block_green").attr({
      x: x
    });
    x--;
  }

 function move_up() {
    $("#block_green").attr({
      y: y
    });
    y--;
  }

 function move_right() {
    $("#block_green").attr({
      x: x
    });
    x++;
  }

 function move_down() {
    $("#block_green").attr({
      y: y
    });
    y++;
  }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}

svg {
 background-color: black;
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
}

#block_green {
 fill: black;
 stroke: #00ff00;
 stroke-width: .5px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<svg>
 <rect x="4" y="4" width="80" height="60" id="block_green"/>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

The code doesn't seem to work here, so you may want to visit http://codepen.io/julian-a-avar/pen/PqZvxp to see it in action, and you may want to check an editor, because as I said before, **The preview doesn't seem to work here**!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make the loop seperate and set variables that determine which `keys` are pressed.

Use `keydown` to set the variables to `true` and `keyup` to set the variables back to `false`.

Something similar to this:

```
$(function() {
    var y = 4;
  var x = 4;
    var n;
    var move;
    var leftPressed = false;
    var rightPressed = false;
    var downPressed = false;
    var upPressed = false;
    setInterval(function(){
        if(leftPressed){
            move_left();
        }else if(rightPressed){
            move_right();
        }
        if(upPressed){
            move_up();
        }else if(downPressed){
            move_down();
        }
    },.01)
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        switch(e.which) {
            case 37: // left
                        leftPressed = true;
                break;
            case 38: // up
                        upPressed = true;
                break;
            case 39: // right
                        rightPressed =true;
                break;
            case 40: // down
                        downPressed = true;
                break;
            default:
                        return;
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $(document).keyup(function(e) {
        switch(e.which) {
            case 37: // left
                        leftPressed = false;
                break;
            case 38: // up
                        upPressed = false;
                break;
            case 39: // right
                        rightPressed =false;
                break;
            case 40: // down
                        downPressed = false;
                break;
            default:
                        return;
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    function move_left() {
    $("#block_green").attr({
      x: x
    });
    x--;
  }

    function move_up() {
    $("#block_green").attr({
      y: y
    });
    y--;
  }

    function move_right() {
    $("#block_green").attr({
      x: x
    });
    x++;
  }

    function move_down() {
    $("#block_green").attr({
      y: y
    });
    y++;
  }


});
```

Notice `setInterval` is just checking the variables to determine which methods to call to move the box.

Here is a [codepen with an example](http://codepen.io/weeksdev/pen/jPqdMy)

**Question 2**

*How to adjust the speed of the moving block?*

One way to adjust the speed is to set a variable that determines how much `x` or `y` changes with each pass in `setInterval`.  So make another variable `n` and setting that value higher makes the block move faster and lower makes it move slower.

Additionally, you asked if there are ways to shorten up the code.  There are probably numerous ways that code could be improved if you get creative.  Below I've provided an example with the variable `n` and provided one way you could shorten up the code.  Instead of having variables for every key pressed just have two variables for the horizontal and vertical axis:

```
$(function() {
    var y = 4;
  var x = 4;
    var n = 1;
    var move;
    var xDirection = 0;
    var yDirection = 0;
    setInterval(function(){
        x = x + (xDirection * n);
        y = y + (yDirection * n);
        $("#block_green").attr({
      y: y,
            x: x
    });
    },.01)
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
            xDirection = e.which == 37 ? -1 : xDirection;
            xDirection = e.which == 39 ? 1 : xDirection;
            yDirection = e.which == 38 ? -1 : yDirection;
            yDirection = e.which == 40 ? 1 : yDirection;
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $(document).keyup(function(e) {
        xDirection = e.which == 37 ? 0 : xDirection;
            xDirection = e.which == 39 ? 0 : xDirection;
            yDirection = e.which == 38 ? 0 : yDirection;
            yDirection = e.which == 40 ? 0 : yDirection;
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

And here is another [codepen of the changes](http://codepen.io/weeksdev/pen/eNZxvy)

Also i'd recommend looking into some basic game algos (like 80's arcade games, ie Space Invaders, etc)  They will have this kind of game logic.

If you're interested, this video on vimeo is pretty cool and a good example of this kind of dev, [developer creating space invaders real time in javascript](https://vimeo.com/105955605)

Comment: It's really good, but what about speed control? I was modifying the number in `line 21` to change the speed, but it didn't matter what I wrote, it just ept going at the same **slow** speed. Can I make it faster?

Comment: Is there a way of reducing the amount of code? Beacause it *seems* lie a lot o repeated code, but then there is of course, I'm not an expert, can I reduce the code even further? If so, could you show me how? I'm ind of lost here, it is 96 lines o code we are talking about

Comment: @julianavar you can make it faster/slower by adjusting the value that `x` or `y` are changed.  Using the `n` variable you could then set the amount either is changed.  I'll add to my answer